# identityserver3 custom usersevice not being called

Tags: authentication, active-directory, identityserver3

[Edited: Added the UserService code]

When the following code inside my IdentityServer has the ADUserService remarked and the .UseInmemory(MemUser.TempUser) code unremarked, all works ok.

When the InMemory is remarked, and the two ADUserService lines unremarked as in the code below, the same login screen is shown but this time fails. When debugging no log is shown and the ADUserService is not entered during login, but only during the startup code being called.

***Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?***

```
        // identityServer factory
        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
        //            .UseInMemoryUsers(MemUser.TempUser) // Fix: Remove temp users!!
                    .UseInMemoryClients(CrbAuthClients.Get())
                    .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.AllSupportedScopes);

        var userService = new ADUserService();
        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => userService);



        // identityServer go!!
        var options = new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SigningCertificate = Certificate.Load(),
            AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions 
                    { 
                        SignInMessageThreshold = 1 // default is 5, prevents "Header Too Long" error
                    },
            Factory = factory
        };

        app.UseIdentityServer(options);
```

Could this be due to my using Visual Studio and its IIS Express where the https is not verified for either of the IDServ3 server (in Nancy) or my MVC client?

Could it be that I need to add CORS policy service?  When do I need that?  I'm calling the authentication from a separate MVC project and website.

```
factory.CorsPolicyService = new Registration<ICorsPolicyService>(new DefaultCorsPolicyService { AllowAll = true });
```

Could it be an issue that I formerly used inMem users, and now there is some kind of cache somewhere still using them?  (I checked the bob-secret which stopped working after the change, and returns to work when changed back to in-memory users)

----- Edited -----

Perhaps it is due to me not using an ldapConnectionDelegate ? 
Do I need to?

Here's the code:

```
namespace Crb.Auth.AuthServer.Securing
{
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.DirectoryServices;
    using System.Security.Claims;

    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
    using IdentityServer3.Core;
    using IdentityServer3.Core.Services;
    using IdentityServer3.Core.Models;
    using IdentityServer3.Core.Extensions;
    using IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default;

    using Serilog;

    // according to gist https://gist.github.com/rmbrunet/6c5c2ba2b8fb03fbc359
    // from rmbrunet on Stack Exchange here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1366

    // A slightly cleaner but less explicit approach (not used here) is in https://gist.github.com/tjrobinson/0ad6c790e90d7a385eb1
    // from rajarameshvarma on Stack Exchange here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/995

    // Startup code is taken from the CustomUserService project in the IdentityServer3 Samples.

    public class ADUserService : UserServiceBase //UserServiceBase
    {
        static class ADAttributes
        {
            public static string SamAccountName = "samaccountname";
            public static string Mail = "mail";
            public static string UserGroup = "usergroup";
            public static string DisplayName = "displayname";
            public static string Department = "department";
            public static string StreetAddress = "streetAddress";
            public static string Phone = "telephoneNumber";
            public static string State = "st";
            public static string City = "l";
            public static string Zip = "postalCode";
            public static string Surname = "sn";
            public static string Givenname = "givenName";
        }

        const string ActiveDirectoryConnectionStringname = "CnnActiveDir";

        #region setup and construction
        //Func<string, string> _ldapConnectionDelegate; //Delegate that receives the domain and returns the LDAP connection string.

        // default ctor reads from connection string
        public ADUserService()//Func<string, string> ldapConnectionDelegate)
        {
            //_ldapConnectionDelegate = ldapConnectionDelegate;
            //Log.Debug("ADUserService called");
        }
        //.. region setup and construction
        #endregion

        #region authenticate with claims

        #region authenticate external - not supported
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IdentityServer3.Core.Models.AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateExternalAsync(IdentityServer3.Core.Models.ExternalIdentity externalUser, IdentityServer3.Core.Models.SignInMessage message)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticateResult>(null);
        }
        #endregion

        public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateLocalAsync(
            string userDomainAndName, // sometimes referred to as 'the subject'
            string password,
            SignInMessage message)
        {

            bool isUserValid = false;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userDomainAndName) 
                || userDomainAndName.IndexOf(@"\") < 1) // expected: some domain name given followed by a backslash
            {
                Log.Debug("Supplied username missing domain. Authentication denied.");
                return Task.FromResult<AuthenticateResult>(null); // Failed!! 
            }
            var split = userDomainAndName.ToLower().Split('\\'); //username assumed to be in the form domain\user
            string domain = split[0];
            string username = split[1];


            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            {
                isUserValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
            }

            if (!isUserValid)
            {
                Log.Debug("Authentication attempt failed for {0}", userDomainAndName);
                return Task.FromResult<AuthenticateResult>(null);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticateResult>(
                new AuthenticateResult(subject: username.ToLower(), name: username));
        }

        #region pre-authenticate async - not supported
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IdentityServer3.Core.Models.AuthenticateResult> PreAuthenticateAsync(IdentityServer3.Core.Models.SignInMessage message)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticateResult>(null);
        }
        #endregion
        //..region authenticate
        #endregion

        #region profile

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim>> GetProfileDataAsync(
            System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal principal,
            IEnumerable<string> requestedClaimTypes = null)
        {

            List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> claims = new List<Claim>(); //x null;


            string subject = principal.GetSubjectId();
            if ( ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject) )
                claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject, subject)); // notice: idsrv3 short name convention as opposed to claims with full type

            SearchResult result = findUser(subject);
            if (result != null &&
                result.Properties.Contains(ADAttributes.Mail) &&
                result.Properties.Contains(ADAttributes.DisplayName))
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, (String)result.Properties[ADAttributes.Mail][0]));
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, (String)result.Properties[ADAttributes.DisplayName][0]));

                if (result.Properties.Contains(ADAttributes.Surname))
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, (String)result.Properties[ADAttributes.Surname][0]));

                if (result.Properties.Contains(ADAttributes.Givenname))
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, (String)result.Properties[ADAttributes.Givenname][0]));

                //Is there an address?
                if (result.Properties.Contains(ADAttributes.State)
                    && result.Properties.Contains(ADAttributes.StreetAddress)
                    && result.Properties.Contains(ADAttributes.City)
                    && result.Properties.Contains(ADAttributes.Zip))
                {

                    string state = (String)result.Properties[ADAttributes.State][0];
                    string street = (String)result.Properties[ADAttributes.StreetAddress][0];
                    string city = (String)result.Properties[ADAttributes.City][0];
                    string zip = (String)result.Properties[ADAttributes.Zip][0];

                    string address = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2} {3}", street, city, state, zip);
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.StreetAddress, address));
                }

                // Get roles from AD user groups
                var prince = principal.Identity as UserPrincipal;
                var groups = prince.GetGroups();
                foreach (var group in groups)
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "dpn:" + group.DisplayName+",dtn:"+group.DistinguishedName ));

                claims = claims.Where(x => requestedClaimTypes.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
            }

            return Task.FromResult(claims.AsEnumerable());
        }
        //.. region profile
        #endregion

        #region sign-out

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task SignOutAsync(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal subject)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
        //..region sign-out
        #endregion

        #region internals

        SearchResult findUser(string subject)
        {
            string[] a = subject.Split('\\');

            string domain = a[0];
            string username = a[1];

            string node = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ActiveDirectoryConnectionStringname].ConnectionString;
                            //x _ldapConnectionDelegate(domain);


            using (DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(node))
            {
                using (DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot))
                {

                    search.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(SAMAccountName={0}))", username);
                    //search.PropertiesToLoad.Add( Constants.ADAttributes.SamAccountName );
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.Mail);
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.UserGroup);
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.DisplayName);
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.Surname);
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.Givenname);
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.Department);
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.StreetAddress);
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.Phone);
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.State);
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.City);
                    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADAttributes.Zip);

                    return search.FindOne();
                }
            }
        }

        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> IsActiveAsync(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            string subject = principal.GetSubjectId(); // this should return the "distinguished name" (sub.maindomain/username)
            SearchResult result = findUser(subject);
            return Task.FromResult(result != null);
        }
        //.. region internals
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe what I'm doing wrong is that I don't have a "context function".

I'll edit the question and add the userService code

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with what you're doing.   Have you checked the logs?

I've found them to be really useful when implementing IdServer.  You can get it to write out to the console using [Serilog](http://serilog.net/) really easily.

Here's some sample code;

```cs
public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .WriteTo.Trace()
        .CreateLogger();

    //id server initialisation...
}
```

Comment: Yes I use serilog. Nothing happens after calling the constructor, the constructor itself is called (and does nothing) Then after pressing login on the IDSrv3 login page with the username and credentials it simply responds that the user is not authorized